# Calling Request.Execute Method to use REST service causes ASP.NET Web Page to load infinitely

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, model-view-controller, bing-maps

I'm trying to use the Bing Maps Rest Toolkit to geocode a UK Postcode. The code should geocode an address and then pass it to an ASP.Net Webpage, where the geocoded address is used to plot a waypoint on a Map.

The Application builds with no errors, but whenever I try to run it, the page times out before anything is displayed. I've deduced that it fails when the Rest API is called on this line:

`var response = await request.Execute();`

aside from that, I'm not sure what's wrong. I'm very new to this, so some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance, and my full code is as follows:

**MapController.cs**

```
public class MapController : Controller
{

    // GET: Map
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        StopLists model = new StopLists();

        var Stops = new List<Stops>()
        {
            new Stops (1, "Stoke Station", null , "ST4 2AA"),

        };

        model.StopList = Stops;

        foreach (var StopLocation in model.StopList)
        {   
            Task<Location> gc = AddGeocode(StopLocation.Postcode);
            StopLocation.Geocode = gc.Result;
            
        };

        return View();

    }            


    public async Task<Location> AddGeocode(String Postcode)
    {
        
        var request = new GeocodeRequest()
        {
            Query = Postcode,
            IncludeIso2 = true,
            IncludeNeighborhood = true,
            MaxResults = 25,
            BingMapsKey = "Placeholder Bing Maps Key"
        };

        var response = await request.Execute();

        //sets responce type to location type, and assigns the value to the geocode
        Location Geocode = response.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location;

        return Geocode;

    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title></title>

</head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="myMap" style='position:relative;width:600px;height:400px; top: 0px; left: 0px;'></div>
    <div id="itineraryContainer"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetMap() {

            var MapsKey = '<My Bing Maps Key>';

            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
                credentials: MapsKey,
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(53.0146, -2.1864),
                zoom: 17
            });

            var center = map.getCenter();

            getRoute(map);

            getTraffic(map);

        }

        function getRoute(map) {

            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function () {
                var directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

                //Set Route Mode to driving
                directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving });
                
                @if (Model.StopList != null)
                {
                    foreach(var StopLocation in Model.StopList)
                    {
                        @:var Stop = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
                            @:address:'@StopLocation.Name', location: @StopLocation.Geocode;
                        @:});
                        @:directionsManager.addWaypoint(Stop);
                    }
                }

                // Shows where the written directions will be rendered
                directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: '#itineraryContainer' });

                directionsManager.calculateDirections();

            });
        }

        function getTraffic(map) {
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Traffic', function () {
                var trafficManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Traffic.TrafficManager(map);
                trafficManager.show();
            });
        }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
    <p>
    </p>
</form>
<p>
    &nbsp;
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Removed Bing Maps Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `AddGeocode` method is async but you never await it. In your C# create an array of the `AddGeocode` tasks then outside of the loop use `await Task.WhenAll` to run them in parallel. This will help with performance and ensure all have processed before continuing.

A couple of other considerations on architecture:

- If the locations you will be geocoding are known ahead of time and don't change constantly, consider geocoding those ahead of time and storing the results in a database. This will significantly reduce costs and increase performance. This is a standard practice in most location finding type apps.
- If the locations change often and geocoding isn't an option. Currently your code does all the geocode requests from the server side, then sends down the results. This means more compute and more http requests on your server which will make this less scalable than if you offload that processing to the client. Consider making the geocode calls within the browser. This will mean the compute processing and those http requests will be made by the end users computer which will lessen the usage on your server and allow it to handle more users. I don't have an example for doing this with Bing Maps, but here is a similar example that uses Azure Maps: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Methods%20for%20geocoding%20multiple%20addresses

Comment: This solved it, thanks so much. I'm planning to store the items in the database, but I just wanted to get this part working first. I didn't know about `await Task.WhenAll` though, and will definitely incorporate that. Again, thanks for your helpful advice.